# EMEDITOR Bookmark lines that end with specific letter (for example emails .de, .ch etc)

Tags: emeditor

I am trying to bookmark only lines (in my case emails) that end with specific suffix.
For example .de or .ch or .it
But if I try to bookmark it takes also some email that is john.it@hotmail.com (so it bookmarks this line which is [name dot it @])
Excel has this feature SORT by: Ends with: [Check out excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpzP4.png)

I cannot find a feature that does this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Filter to bookmark lines? You can use Regular Expressions to specify a more precise pattern. In this case, you are looking for the string `.it` at the end of a line, so use the metacharacter `$` which matches the end of a line.

Enable Regular Expressions in Filter with the button on the toolbar or the radio button in Advanced Filter. The find string would be like `\.it$`. Since the dot `.` has special meaning in Regular Expressions, I escaped it with backslash.

[image]

You can bookmark the filtered lines.

I use this helpful site to test my Regex (Regular Expressions): https://regexr.com/735r9.

I'm editing this answer because I also thought of another solution. You can add a second filter to negate `.it@` matches. This would not use Regular Expressions.

[image]

As you can see, I match `.it`, but then with the second filter, I negate any `.it@` matches by selecting the Negative checkmark. This might be easier to understand for some people. If you have a large file, you may notice that this method is faster since it does not use regex.